# Get an IFRAME element by name does not work anymore?

Tags: javascript

I have this very old JS that worked in IE8 that was doing this:

```
window.document.getElementById("frameModalityList")
```

Here is what I want to fetch:

```
<iframe name="frameModalityList" src="iframe_advanced_list.jsp" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="advanced_list" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

Now, when I try it in IE9/10, Chrome, I get an error:

> SCRIPT5007: Caught exception occurred : Unable to get property 'contentWindow' of undefined or null reference

What is the new proper way to get the IFRAME element?

Comment: Change `name` to `id` ??

Comment: It used to work, and the guy who did it, used 'getElementById' every where, what a pain... I suppose back then it was ok, I'm talking about 6 years ago.

Comment: Beware of id and name attribute mixups when using getElementById in Internet Explorer... see the link in my answer

Comment: @pinkpanther, thx, I was actually looking for a bit more on 'backward compatibility' since it used to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New EDIT:** That old code worked because of some possible bug (or intended) in the old versions of internet explorer.

From this [Beware of id and name attribute mixups when using getElementById in Internet Explorer](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/)

**When using getElementById to get a reference to an element via the id attribute, Internet Explorer for Windows (and some versions of Opera) will also match an element whose name attribute contains the same value.**

First given answer:

You are fetching by `id` but you didn't set the `id` in `iframe` element

`window.document.getElementById("frameModalityList")`

change name attribute to id `iframe` to

```
<iframe id="frameModalityList" src="iframe_advanced_list.jsp" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="advanced_list" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

because you haven't set the id but name try this:

```
window.document.getElementByName("frameModalityList")
```

or insert the id into the html:

```
<iframe id="frameModalityList" name="frameModalityList" src="iframe_advanced_list.jsp" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="advanced_list" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>

window.document.getElementById("frameModalityList")
```